# Matlab: Why does this piece of code works (expected an error)

Tags: matlab, indexing

I got these two vectors, with 9 elements each:

```
>> length(a)

ans =

     9

>> length(c)

ans =

     9
```

And this code:

```
z=0;
s=0;
temp=0;
for K = 1:length(c)
    temp=c(K)*a(K);
    z=prod(1-a(K+1:end));
    s=s+temp*z;
end
```

The vector's a indexing is done via K itterator. I would expect that index would blow. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Why do you expect it to fail? since `length(a)` and `length(c)` are the same, `K` won't go out of bounds for `a`. Perhaps you're thinking of iterators as pointers such as in C++, but in MATLAB we don't have that: `K` is simply a number that goes from `1:length(c)`, and you're indexing the matrices `a` and `c` with this number.

Comment: @Steve Heim, you are only considering the `temp=c(K)*a(K)` line, not the `a(K+1:end)` indexing.

Answer (score 5):

It does not give an error because

```
prod([]) = 1
```

So after `K+1` becomes `10`, `a` becomes `[]` and the output becomes

```
z = prod(1-[])
z = 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Regarding *why* it's an empty array, see the docs for [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html): `The end function also serves as the last index in an indexing expression. In that context, end is the same as size(X,k) when used as part of the kth index into array X.`